# Can a postgres function return multiple record sets

Tags: postgresql, set, record

I have a mySql sp I need to convert to postgres function.  The SP can pull different data sets depending on the parametes put in.  this is the mysql code:

```
IF upper(type) = 'PROJ'then
            if upper(number) = 'ALL' then
                    SELECT * FROM CLMAppViews.vw_project_profile order by `Project Title`;
            else                
                    SELECT * FROM CLMAppViews.vw_project_profile where `Project Number`  = number order by `Project Title`;
            end if  ; 
    else    
        if upper(number) = 'ALL' then 
                    SELECT * from CLMAppViews.vw_proposal_profile order by title;
            else
                    SELECT * from CLMAppViews.vw_proposal_profile where `Opportunity ID / Proposal ID` = number order by title;
        end if ;
end if;
```

can anyone suggest how I may be able to replicate this in Postgres? The problem I'm running into is that the result set can have different data types depending on the path taken in the code.

Comment: But in your example the types are always the same...

Comment: You are not returning multiple result sets but a single "variable" one. In theory at least, since you are always returning the same columns from the same table.

Comment: but i am not retuning the same columns.  The MySql stored procedure returns different column names and data types depending on the view that is called.